# Neccessity of push and pop operands on CPUs

Tags: assembly, stack, cpu, cpu-architecture, att

Why do we have commands like push and pop?

From what I understand `pop` and `push` are basically the same as doing a (`mov` then `add`) and (`sub` then `mov`) on `esp` respectively.

---

For example wouldn't:

```
pushl %eax
```

be equivalent to:

```
subl $4, %esp
movl %eax, (%esp-4)
```

*please correct me if stack access is not `(%esp-4)`, I'm still learning assembly*

---

The only true benefit I can see is if doing both operation simultaneously offers some advantage; however I don't see how it could.

Comment: It saves space, and x86 is actually a CISC design so why not.

Comment: @harold it provides no extra function that's why not. The CPU still spends time on both operations.

Comment: Yes.. but it's a CISC design, so it was designed to make it easy for assembly programmers to work with by providing instructions that "do a lot". See also: `leave`, `enter`, `rep movsb` etc. And it really does save a lot of space in bytes as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

But then, there's no reason for a `CALL` instruction, either. After all, you can simulate a call with:

```
sub esp,4
mov [esp-4], offset return_address
jmp myproc
```

And there's no need for a `RET` instruction, either, because you can simulate it with:

```
mov eax,[esp]
add esp,4
jmp [eax]
```

If you look hard enough, you'll find lots of instructions that can be simulated by combining other instructions. What's the point?

The answer to these types of questions is rooted in the long history of the x86 processor family, and in processors that came before it. The designers studied how programmers use processors and created an instruction set that was efficient in terms of execution speed and memory use.

In the late '70s, 64 kilobytes was a lot of RAM, and RAM was much slower. Every instruction byte was precious, and there was a huge amount of overhead just fetching an instruction from memory. It was not uncommon for instruction fetch to take longer than execution. So there was a huge performance gain to be had by encoding things in as few instruction bytes as possible.

RAM is still incredibly slow when compared to CPU clock speeds, so there's still a gain to be had by encoding in as few instruction bytes as possible. It's true that the large CPU caches we have help a great deal, as does branch prediction and prefetch logic, but every byte transferred from RAM to the CPU cache is still expensive. It pays to be frugal with instruction encodings.

About calling procedures:

The standard way of calling procedures in assembly language is to push the parameters and then `call` the procedure. For example, this passes two dword values:

```
push eax
push ebx
call proc    ; pushes the return address and jumps to proc
...

proc:
  ; at this point, [esp] contains the return address
```

The `ret` instruction pops the return address into the instruction pointer.

Somebody has to clean up the stack, of course. The caller can clean up the stack by incrementing the stack pointer. Or the called procedure can clean up the stack by using `ret 8`, which will pop the return address and increment the stack pointer.

See http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/asm/calling.html for more info on calling conventions.

Comment: I thought `subl $4, %esp` is required before a call anyway or at least before an interrupt it is; also, why does `%esp` have the return address in your example?

Comment: @Hawken: You have to put the return address somewhere.

Comment: but why is the return address at the stack pointer? Is this assuming you cleared the stack vars you used for the called function?

Comment: @Hawken: The standard calling conventions push the parameters and then the return address. (Actually, the `call` instruction pushes the return address.) So the return address is always at the "top" of the stack (i.e. pointed to by SP).

Comment: but if you push your own values to the stack, `%esp` is not at the return address, so I'm guessing you need to 'reset' the stack to how it was before subroutine began execution? Sorry, if this is painfully obvious to anyone familiar w/ assembly.

Comment: @Hawken: See my additional information, especially the link to information about calling conventions.

Answer (score 2):

Well. If you have two instructions, then they probably use more space. Which requires cpu to transfer more data. And that takes more time. Two separate instructions also typically require more cpu resources. Even if cpu parallelizes them, there is more work for fetcher, decoder...
If you try to remove all but absolutely neccessary instructions you end up with turing machine. Ultimate risc, but not very effective in practice.

Answer (score 1):

1 opcode > 2 opcodes, at least when you are trying to reduce CPU usage.

Comment: I understand, this saves memory on part of the executable, but both operations must still be carried out. Perhaps this is the kind of thing that inspired the RISC architecture?

Comment: Hmm, it possibly inspired the *demise* of RISC architectures.

Comment: @hanspassant why? RISC is more predictable per instruction, CISC seems to do nothing except make a 'shortcut' which still takes the same amount of time to execute (not much of a shortcut).  From what I have read of CISC it is slower in many scenarios due to these shortcuts. If I understand correctly something like `addl %eax,%ebx` will waste time checking if `%eax` and `%ebx` are memory addresses before running the `addl` because  it needs to support using a memory address in place of registers.

Comment: @Hawken: You might want to read a bit more about RISC vs. CISC. One would expect, if RISC were significantly better (i.e. faster), that people would be using them more. Yes, RISC is more predictable per instruction. But a program written on a RISC processor will require more instruction bytes than the equivalent program on a CISC processor. And instruction fetch isn't free.

Comment: @hanspassant the main problem of RISC, I hear, was poor adoption; Apple is rumored to have switched due to PowerPC chips producing too much heat for portables, and PowerPC being less developed due to poor adoption.

Comment: Hey let's not get off topic here with RISCy chatter :)  _"addl %eax,%ebx will waste time checking if %eax and %ebx"_ Sometimes, most x86 CPUs built in the last 6 years will try to self-optimize opcodes, so (esp in Intel) some opcodes will be run out of order slightly to have 1+ instructions run at the same time, pre-load memory, etc.  So even if there are costs involved, when ran you MAY see just as fast or faster code due to the CPU out smarting the programmer ;)

Comment: To help figure out if push/pop or mov,add/sub/mov is best for a particular situation, read the Instruction tables here: http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals
Dr Agner helped many programmers optimize their code!

Comment: `addl %eax,%ebx` has no memory operand, why should it check if they are memory addresses or not?